# Как правильно читать исходники?

Tags: java

В Java без году неделя и вот меня научили пользоваться JavaDoc. Вот часть описания интерфейса `CharSequence`:`Returns a stream of {@code int} zero-extending the {@code char} values from this sequence.`
Не могу понять как переводить и понимать такие участки текста в контексте предложения, как:`{@code int}, {@code char}`? Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утилита JavaDoc конвертирует комментарии написанные в определенном формате в HTML файлы, которые можно отрыть браузером и в нем читать. Описание формата комментариев вы можете прочитать в [javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html)

Что касается `{@code text}`, то этот тэг заключает текст в HTML тэг `<code></code>`, подробное описание тэга [{@code}](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#code)

Вот как выглядит документация по [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) с указанным вами описанием. 
Обратите внимание, что `int` и `char` начертаны другим шрифтом.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло